# Extract information about education institute, grades, year and degree from text using NLP in Python

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, spacy

I want to extract information about education institute, degree, year of passing and grades (CGPA/GPA/Percentage) from text using NLP in Python.
For example, if I have the input:

> NBN Sinhgad School Of Engineering,Pune 2016 - 2020 Bachelor of Engineering Computer Science CGPA: 8.78 Vidya Bharati Chinmaya Vidyalaya,Jamshedpur 2014 - 2016 Intermediate-PCM,Economics CBSE Percentage: 88.8 Vidya Bharati Chinmaya Vidyalaya,Jamshedpur 2003 - 2014 Matriculation,CBSE CGPA: 8.6 EXPERIENCE

I want the ouput:

```js
[{
  "Institute": "NBN Sinhgad School Of Engineering",
  "Degree": "Bachelor of Engineering Computer Science",
  "Grades": "8.78",
  "Year of Passing": "2020"
}, {
  "Institute": "Vidya Bharati Chinmaya Vidyalaya",
  "Degree": "Intermediate-PCM,Economics",
  "Grades": "88.8",
  "Year of Passing": "2016"
}, {
  "Institute": "Vidya Bharati Chinmaya Vidyalaya",
  "Degree": "Matriculation,CBSE",
  "Grades": "8.6",
  "Year of Passing": "2014"
}]
```

Can it be done without training any custom NER model? Is there any pre-trained NER available to do this?

Answer (score 1):

yes it is possible to parse the data without training any custom NER model. you have
to build the custom rules to parse the data.

In your example case, you can the extract data by regex and pattern identification like institute always before the year of passing or something. if it is not unordered,you have to go by keywords like `school, institute,college ans so on...` either way it depends on your case.

```
import re

txt = '''NBN Sinhgad School Of Engineering,Pune 2016 - 2020 Bachelor of Engineering Computer Science CGPA: 8.78 
Vidya Bharati Chinmaya Vidyalaya,Jamshedpur 2014 - 2016 Intermediate-PCM,Economics CBSE Percentage: 88.8
Vidya Bharati Chinmaya Vidyalaya,Jamshedpur 2003 - 2014 Matriculation,CBSE CGPA: 8.6 EXPERIENCE'''

# extract grades
grade_regex = r'(?:\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2})'
grades = re.findall(grade_regex, txt)

# extract years
year_regex = r'(?:\d{4}\s?-\s?\d{4})'
years = re.findall(year_regex, txt)


# function to replace a value in string
def replacer(string, noise_list):
    for v in noise_list:
        string = string.replace(v, ":")
    return string


# extract college
data = replacer(txt, years)
cleaned_text = re.sub("(?:\w+\s?\:)", "**", data).split('\n')
college = []
degree = []
for i in cleaned_text:
    split_data = i.split("**")
    college.append(split_data[0].replace(',', '').strip())
    degree.append(split_data[1].strip())
parsed_output = []
for i in range(len(grades)):
    parsed_data = {
        "Institute": college[i],
        "Degree": degree[i],
        "Grades": grades[i],
        "Year of Passing": years[i].split('-')[1]
    }
    parsed_output.append(parsed_data)
print(parsed_output)

>>>> [{'Institute': 'NBN Sinhgad School Of Engineering', 'Degree': 'Bachelor of Engineering Computer Science', 'Grades': '8.78', 'Year of Passing': ' 2020'}, {'Institute': 'Vidya Bharati Chinmaya Vidyalaya', 'Degree': 'Intermediate-PCM,Economics CBSE', 'Grades': '88.8', 'Year of Passing': ' 2016'}, {'Institute': 'Vidya Bharati Chinmaya Vidyalaya', 'Degree': 'Matriculation,CBSE', 'Grades': '8.6', 'Year of Passing': ' 2014'}]
```

Comment: Thanks for this reply. There are many patterns actually, so it was hard for me to generalize the pattern. But let me try out this and I will let you know

Comment: one more suggestion: you can use `spellcheck` which might funnels out named institution like `vidhya`  and identify other institutions by keywords like `university`,'institute`.

Comment: sorry I didn't understand the spellcheck part. Can you tell me more?

Comment: check this https://pyspellchecker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/  i mean institution that does not having identification keywords like school,college,university etc can be filtered by spell check. because mostly named institution like `Vidya Bharati Chinmaya Vidyalaya` will be an error

Comment: very interesting. Thanks for sharing! I was thinking of manually implementing a fuzzy matching algorithm for the spell check. The spellchecker module would definitely simplify it!